# categories: parent and children - to display using twitter bootstrap

Tags: channel, categories

I am using twitter bootstrap and was wondering if it is possible using EE's native category channel tags, to append a class="dropdown-toggle" to any parent category that contains children, and apply class="dropdown-menu" to the children's unordered list.

```
<ul class="nav nav-stacked products_nav">
    <li><a href="products.php">All products</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown">
        <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Corn Tortillas</a>

        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="products_corn_tortilla1.php">Tortilla 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#corn_tortilla2">Tortilla 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#corn_tortilla3">Tortilla 3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="products_better-for-you-tortillas.php">Better-For-You Tortillas</a></li>

    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#">Artisan Style Tortillas</a></li>
    <li><a href="products_wraps.php">Wraps</a></li>

    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#">Tortilla Chips</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#">Tostadas</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#">Taco Shells &amp; Kits</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#">Chicharrones</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#">Salsa, Dips, Toppings</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#">All Others</a></li>
</ul>
```

[image]

I took a look at this add-on, but from looking thru the examples, it doesn't seem to do what I need: http://gwcode.com/add-ons/gwcode-categories

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Brad,
i've got something similar working on a local site.
Was able to achieve what you're trying to do using a similiar addon by the same developer GWcode [CatMenu](http://gwcode.com/add-ons/gwcode-catmenu)

You can use my code as a starting point..

```
<nav id="menu">
{exp:gwcode_catmenu cat_url_title="{segment_1}" }
{if no_results}<!-- if no valid category was provided in the URL segment show only root categories as our menu-->
{exp:channel:categories
channel="demo"
parent_only="yes"
disable="member_data|pagination"
}
<a href="{path='{category_url_title}'}" title="{category_name}"><span>{category_name} {if category_name !=""}<i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>{/if}</span></a>
{/exp:channel:categories}
{/if}
<a href="{path='{complete_path}'}"{if active} class="current"{/if} title="{cat_name}">{if gw:open} class="current"{/if} {cat_name} {if has_children} <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>{/if}</a>
{/exp:gwcode_catmenu}
</nav>
```